# Php - echo line 6 from Text file

Tags: php

How to echo line 6 from Text file?

I have tried this.
But i dont know  what to do further. This is not working.
What to change?

```
   <?
   $file1 = "file/datum2.html";
   $lines = file($file1);
   foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
    echo $line[6];
    echo "<br>";
   }

  ?>
```

Datum2.html:

1-juli-2016
2-juli-2016
3-juli-2016
4-juli-2016
5-juli-2016
6-juli-2016

This is the result now with help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja5yl.jpg)

Comment: If you're going straight to the element of the array you want the value of, you don't need a loop. Just use echo $lines[6];

Comment: you never said what does not work or echos anything. Edit oh yeah, it doesnt echo anything; my bad.

Comment: What is the 6 line in datum2.html. kindly provide datum2.html..

Comment: why aren't you using a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo implode('<br />', array_slice(file('file/datum2.html'), 0, 6));
```

OR

```
echo implode('\n', array_slice(file('file/datum2.html'), 0, 6));
```

Comment: Can you maybe answer one more Simple question? How to store the echo in a variable?

Comment: $lines = implode('\n', array_slice(file('file/datum2.html'), 0, 6));

Comment: @John If this was the answer you were looking for, your question is very unclear and I highly recommend you to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Rizier123 I read only first line in his question, the rest of the question isn't clear to understand

Comment: @Mostafa Well the first line is also misleading when this was the answer. Because he writes that he wants line 6. But what he actually wanted was line 1 to 6. (Also you know that you can edit your answer and don't have to post a new one every time.)

Comment: @Rizier123 I read it quickly and I understood that he wants to display the first 6 lines, because he was using foreach, I talk about the first question before any updates

Comment: @Rizier123 I think that all my answers are correct, may be one of them is useful for another person

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file1 = "file/datum2.html";
$lines = file($file1);
$i= 0;
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
    $i++;
    echo $line[$line_num];
    echo "<br>";
    if($i == 6) break;
}

?>
```

Comment: It puts out everything correct but All letters are UNDER Each other?

Comment: Ok, I will change the answer

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$file1 = "file/datum2.html";
$lines = file($file1);
$output = array_slice($lines, 0, 6, true);
 foreach($output as $line_num => $line)
    {
        echo $line[$line_num];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

test the code using array_slice with true and without true

Comment: This is the echo: 
2
-
j
u
l

Comment: are you sure that the file has more than 6 lines?

Comment: I added a new answer, check it

Comment: It works also. But letters are UNDER Each other. Not like in the Text file

Comment: See picture for output

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should works

```
<?php
    $file1 = "file/datum2.html";
   $lines = file($file1);
   $lines = explode(" ",$lines);
   echo $lines[5];
?>
```